# What's the representation of a set of char in PASCAL?

Tags: memory, char, set, pascal, data-representation

They ask me to represet a set of char like into "map memory". What chars are in the set? The teacher told us to use ASCII code, into a set of 32 bytes.

A have this example, the set {'A', 'B', 'C'}

(The 7 comes from 0111)

= {00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 70 00
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   00}

Comment: Why downvote this question? What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sets in pascal can be represented in memory with one bit for every element; if the bit is 1, the element is present in the set.

A "set of char" is the set of ascii char, where each element has an ordinal value from 0 to 255 (it should be 127 for ascii, but often this set is extended up to a byte, so there are 256 different characters).

Hence a "set of char" is represented in memory as a block of 32 bytes which contain a total of 256 bits. The character "A" (upper case A) has an ordinal value of 65. The integer division of 65 by 8 (the number of bits a byte can hold) gives 8. So the bit representing "A" in the set resides in the byte number 8. 65 mod 8 gives 1, which is the second bit in that byte.

The byte number 8 will have the second bit ON for the character A (and the third bit for B, and the fourth for C). All the three characters together give the binary representation of 0000.1110 ($0E in hex).

To demonstrate this, I tried the following program with turbo pascal:

```
var
  ms    : set of char;
  p     : array[0..31] of byte absolute ms;
  i     : integer;

begin
  ms := ['A'..'C'];
  for i := 0 to 31 do begin
    if i mod 8=0 then writeln;
    write(i,'=',p[i],'  ');
  end;
  writeln;
end.
```

The program prints the value of all 32 bytes in the set, thanks to the "absolute" keyword. Other versions of pascal can do it using different methods. Running the program gives this result:

```
0=0  1=0  2=0  3=0  4=0  5=0  6=0  7=0  
8=14  9=0  10=0  11=0  12=0  13=0  14=0  15=0  
16=0  17=0  18=0  19=0  20=0  21=0  22=0  23=0  
24=0  25=0  26=0  27=0  28=0  29=0  30=0  31=0
```

where you see that the only byte different than 0 is the byte number 8, and it contains 14 ($0E in hex, 0000.1110). So, your guess (70) is wrong.

That said, I must add that nobody can state this is always true, because a set in pascal is implementation dependent; so your answer could also be right. The representation used by turbo pascal (on dos/windows) is the most logical one, but this does not exclude other possible representations.